# preg_replace tags issue

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm trying to replace two tags

```
</th> 
</tr>
```

with

```
</th>
</tr>
</thead>
```

I think the line break between the tags is preventing the replacement below from working:

```
$str = preg_replace('/(<\/th>)+(\/tr)/i', '</th></tr></thead>', $str);
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: My suggestion is that you don't use regular expressions to do this but instead a HTML parser. Additionally, check your regex, it looks like that you have missed the one or other character in there.

Comment: Sometimes a HTML parser it's a good option but if it's something tiny, maybe it's not a good idea...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the regex solution:

```
$str = preg_replace('/<\/th>\s*<\/tr>/i', '</th></tr></thead>', $str);
```

Note that the `\s*` matches any whitespace and you were missing `<` and `>` around the `/tr`.

As pointed out above, an HTML/DOM parser might be better suited to what you want to do.